# Proof approach for $n! \ge (n/2)^{n/2}$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

I am having trouble proving that $n! \ge \frac{n}{2}^{\frac{n}{2}}$ for all $n \ge 2$. Intuitively, I can see how this is true. However, I am struggling with a formal proof and dont know which way to go

Comment: is it fair to downvote new members for duplicate questions?

Comment: In a nutshell, the larger half of the expanded terms of n! are all greater than n/2.

Comment: @Robson No, it is downvoted because of its zero-effort and poor formatting.